# MediaInfoList Example for Delphi

Tags: delphi, mediainfo

According to the MediaInfo documentation which is located at http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Support/SDK/Doxygen/class_media_info_lib_1_1_media_info_list.html, the MediaInfoList class is used to gather information about multiple files in one shot.

The problem I have is the MediaInfoDLL.pas file that comes with the download package does not contain any information I need to access this class and I cannot find any examples online that show how to use this class from within Delphi.

If anyone has any references or examples on how I am supposed to access this class then please do share.

Comment: the .DLL download (.7z or .zip) has Delphi code.  Check the download page: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows

Answer (score 0):

That is Visual C++ class, it is absolutely different from Delphi classes.

You may try to compile the whole MediaInfo using C++ Builder instead.
Or make COM class over that class using Visual C++.

Or better not use classes at all. Most simple. And most practical.

Make your own class wrapping non-class API